# Find a specific character in a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I want to find a specific character in a given string of number for example if my input is:

```
1 4 5 7 9 12
```

Then for `4` the answer should be `1`. My code is as follows:

```
secarr = second.split(" ")
answer = secarr.index(number) #here number is a variable which gets the character
puts answer
```

The above method works if I write `"4"` instead of `number` or any other specific character but does not work if I write a variable. Is there a method in ruby to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably your variable `number` is an Integer, and secarr is an `Array of Strings`. Try to cast the number to string:

```
answer = secarr.index(number.to_s)
```

Comment: it was. I kept on thinking about somehow changing the string of numbers to array and didn't even think about simply changing the variable number to a string.